# How to update the value of a textbox and save it to database

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, jsp, servlets

Here i created a dynamically add/remove textboxes and saved it to database and again displayed the rows of data present in database in the webpage as shown below.
[image]

The code is as shown below

taxInfo.jsp

```
<script language="javascript">
                    // Add row to the HTML table


                   function addRow() {    
                        var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); //html table
                        var rowCount = table.rows.length; //no. of rows in table
                        var columnCount =  table.rows[0].cells.length; //no. of columns in table          
                        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount); //insert a row            


                        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);            
                        var element1 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element1.type = "text"; 
                        element1.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element1.setAttribute('name', 'name'+rowCount);
                        cell1.appendChild(element1);      

                        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);            
                        var element2 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element2.type = "text"; 
                        element2.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element2.setAttribute('name', 'value'+rowCount);
                        cell2.appendChild(element2);         

                        var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);            
                        var element3 = document.createElement("input");            
                        element3.type = "text"; 
                        element3.setAttribute('id', 'newInput'); //set the id attribute
                        element3.setAttribute('name', 'taxgroup'+rowCount);

                        cell3.appendChild(element3);

                        var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                        var element4 = document.createElement("input");
                        element4.type = "button";
                        element4.value = "Remove";
                        element4.setAttribute('id', 'newInput');
                        element4.setAttribute('style', 'width:63px');

                        cell4.appendChild(element4);
                        $('table').on('click', 'input[type="button"]', function(e){
                               $(this).closest('tr').remove()
                            })
                                        }  


function deleteRow(id){
    var f=document.form;
    f.method="post";
    f.action='removeRow.jsp?id='+id;
    f.submit();
}
function generate1(){
    var table = document.getElementById('my_table'); 
    var rowCount = table.rows.length;
    var f = document.form;
    f.target="";
    f.method="post";
    f.action='taxInfoDB.jsp?rowCount='+rowCount;
//     f.submit();
}
</script>
 <%!String taxgroup, name, value;

              %>



                <br />
                 <form name="form"  method="post">
            <div align="center">
                 <input type="button" value="Add row"  name="add" onClick="addRow()"  />
<br /><br/>
<b style="padding-right:100px">Name of the Tax</b> <b style="padding-right:100px">Value</b> <b style="padding-right:100px">TaxGroup</b>  <br/>
<table id="my_table" align="center" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                                <tr>

                                        <th></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                        <th></th>
                                         <%
                    int count = 0;
                %>


                                        <%
                                        DBConnect db1 = new DBConnect();
                                        try {
                                             Connection con1 = db1.getCon();
                                             Statement st1 = con1.createStatement();
                                             String query1 = "Select id, TaxGroup,Name,Value from marketing_database.tax_info ORDER BY id;";
                                             ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery(query1);
                                             while (rs1.next()) {
                                                 taxgroup=rs1.getString(2);
                                                 name=rs1.getString(3);
                                                 value=rs1.getString(4);
                                                 id=rs1.getString(1);

                                %>
                                <input id  name = "taxname" type="text" value = <%=name%> />
                                    <input name = "me" type="text" value = <%=value%> />
                                    <input id = "group" name = "group" type="text" value = <%=taxgroup%> />
                                    <input style="width:63px" type="button" value="Remove" onClick="deleteRow('<%=rs1.getString(1)%>')"/>
                              <br/>

                      <% count++;%>

                <% 
                                }
                               con1.close();
                               st1.close();
                               rs1.close();
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }
                        %>


                                </tr>
                                 <tbody>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
   <input type = "hidden" name = "hiddenvalue" value="<%= count%>" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value=" Save" onclick="generate1()" />
</div></div>

            </form>
```

removeRow.jsp

```
<body>
<%
String id = request.getParameter("id");
System.out.println("id is"+id);
try{
    DBConnect db =new DBConnect();
    Connection con = db.getCon();
    String sql ="delete from marketing_database.tax_info where Name = '"+id+"'";
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    con.close();
    ps.close();

        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
        }


response.sendRedirect("taxInfo.jsp");
%>

</body>
```

taxInfoDB.jsp

```
<body>
<%
String row = request.getParameter("rowCount");   
System.out.println("Row Count====="+row);
int rowCount = Integer.parseInt(row);

String taxgroup,name;
String value;
int j=1;
while (j < rowCount) {
    name = request.getParameter("name" + j);
    taxgroup = request.getParameter("taxgroup" + j);
    value = request.getParameter("value" + j);

try{
      DBConnect db =new DBConnect();
      Connection con = db.getCon();
      String sql ="INSERT INTO marketing_database.tax_info (TaxGroup,Name,Value) values (?,?,?);";
      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setString(1, taxgroup);
      ps.setString(2, name);
      ps.setString(3, value);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println(" Saved to tax_info !!");
   con.close();
   ps.close();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}

j = j + 1;

}
response.sendRedirect("taxInfo.jsp");
%>

</body>
```

Now my question is how to save the modified values(For Example if i change the "VAT" of "TaxGroup" to "VAT5.5" and "SS" of "TaxGroup" to "SS5") to the database.And that too when i click on "Save" it should save the modified values as well as when i click on "Add Row" and enter the values in the textbox those values also should be saved as well.

So i need any idea or suggestion on how to do it.Any help will be appreciated

Comment: incase of save you should submit the page just like as form and onsubmit you should write logic to save all rows in dtabase and then reload the page so it will reflect. In case of adding rows, if you want to reflect it in DB at same time then you should use ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

removeRow.jsp

```
<body>
<%
String id = request.getParameter("id");
System.out.println("id is"+id);
try{
    DBConnect db =new DBConnect();
    Connection con = db.getCon();
    String sql ="delete from marketing_database.tax_info where id = '"+id+"'";
    PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    con.close();
    ps.close();

        }
        catch(SQLException ex){
    ex.printStackTrace();
        }


response.sendRedirect("taxInfo.jsp");
%>

</body>
```

taxInfoDB.jsp

```
<body>
<%
String taxg=null,nameg=null,valg=null;
String id = null;
String row = request.getParameter("rowCount");   
System.out.println("Row Count====="+row);
int rowCount = Integer.parseInt(row);
String hiddenvalue = request.getParameter("hiddenvalue");
int hid = Integer.parseInt(hiddenvalue);
System.out.println("hidden are:"+hid);
String taxgroup=null,name=null;
String value=null;
String[] group = request.getParameterValues("group");
String[] taxname = request.getParameterValues("taxname");
String[] me = request.getParameterValues("me");

int j=1;
int k=0;

while (j < rowCount) {
    name = request.getParameter("name" + j);
    taxgroup = request.getParameter("taxgroup" + j);
    value = request.getParameter("value" + j);
System.out.println("value is"+value);
if((name!=null) && (taxgroup!=null) && (value!=null)) {
try{
      DBConnect db =new DBConnect();
      Connection con = db.getCon();
      String sql ="INSERT INTO marketing_database.tax_info (TaxGroup,Name,Value) values (?,?,?);";
      PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
      ps.setString(1, taxgroup);
      ps.setString(2, name);
      ps.setString(3, value);
    ps.executeUpdate();
    System.out.println(" Saved to tax_info !!");
   con.close();
   ps.close();
} catch (SQLException ex) {
ex.printStackTrace();
}

j = j + 1;
}
}

while(k < hid) {
try {
    DBConnect db1 = new DBConnect();
     Connection con1 = db1.getCon();
     Statement st1 = con1.createStatement();
     String query1 = "Select id,TaxGroup,Name,Value from marketing_database.tax_info ORDER BY id;";
     ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery(query1);
     while (rs1.next()) {
         taxg = rs1.getString(2);
         nameg = rs1.getString(3);
         valg = rs1.getString(4);
         id = rs1.getString(1);
         System.out.println(id);


    String group1 = group[k];
    String taxname1  = taxname[k];
    String value2 = me[k];
     System.out.println(group1);
    try{
          DBConnect db2 =new DBConnect();
          Connection con2 = db2.getCon();
          String sql1 ="Update marketing_database.tax_info set TaxGroup = '"+group1+"', Name = '"+taxname1+"', Value= '"+value2+"' where id = '"+id+"'";
          PreparedStatement ps1 = con2.prepareStatement(sql1);
          ps1.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(" Saved to database !!");

       con2.close();
       ps1.close();


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }

    k = k + 1;
     }
     con1.close();
     st1.close();
     rs1.close();
  } catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
}

response.sendRedirect("taxInfo.jsp");
%>

</body>
```